# Is it possible to make net.http.ServeMux match the whole subtree?

Tags: go

I would like to create a ServeMux to match a whole subtree.

For example:

There is a handler is able to process all user-related functions.
It's not nice to list all possible user-related urls like

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()  
mux.Handle("/user/", TestHandler)
mux.Handle("/user/function01", TestHandler)
mux.Handle("/user/function02", TestHandler)
mux.Handle("/user/function03/sub-function01", TestHandler)
...
...
mux.Handle("/user/function100/sub-function01", TestHandler)
mux.Handle("/user/function100/sub-function01/sub-sub-function01", TestHandler)
```

Is it possible to match all urls which starts with '/user' in a single line ?

Answer (score 4):

It will automaticly call the `/user/` handler if the path doesn't exist, for [example](http://play.golang.org/p/S59Fcby05B):

```
func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/user/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "generic user handler: %v\n", req.URL.Path)
    })
    mux.HandleFunc("/user/f1/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "f1 generic handler, %v\n", req.URL.Path)
    })
    mux.HandleFunc("/user/f1/sf1", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "sf1 generic handler, %v\n", req.URL.Path)
    })
    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":9020", mux))
}
```

Produces:

```
➜ curl localhost:9020/user/
generic user handler: /user/
➜ curl localhost:9020/user/f1/
f1 generic handler, /user/f1/
➜ curl localhost:9020/user/f1/sf1
sf1 generic handler, /user/f1/sf1
➜ curl localhost:9020/user/f2
generic user handler: /user/f2
➜ curl localhost:9020/user/f1/sf2
f1 generic handler, /user/f1/sf2
```

Comment: Thank you! It works fine but only one exception. If I try accessing localhost:9020/user (No trailing slash) then I got a 'Moved Permanently' page. Is it possible to also cover this case?

Comment: Its should automatically redirect you to `/user/` in that case, however you can add an extra one for just `/user` I suppose. `mux.HandleFunc("/user", ......)`.